# Interface Injection chapter in DI

Tags: interface, dependency-injection

I just start learning what is Dependency Injection and InversionOfControll is. But I cant get one thing. The interface injection is onle when I define some interface where describe method what need to be realized. And that method gets instance of some class as parameter, and then In class what implements interface just describe body of this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is only a contract that defines what public members a class should implement. It does not control the actual implementation - you need a concrete class to do that.

```
// This is only a contract that defines what members
// all concrete types must implement.
public interface ISomeType
{
    void DoSomething();
}

// This class implements the interface. Therefore, it must
// have all of the methods the contract specifies. In some
// languages, this can be done implicitly just by adding the
// member, but it usually must be public.
public class SomeType : ISomeType
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

When you make a class implement an interface it implicitly means that instances of the class can be cast to the interface type.

```
ISomeType x = new SomeType();
```

Dependency Injection takes advantage of this behavior. You typically define both the interface type and the concrete implementation together in a mapping.

```
container.For<ISomeType>().Use<SomeType>();
```

Then when a service is declared to take ISomeType as a constructor argument, the map is used to determine which concrete type to create an instance of.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly ISomeType someType;

    public SomeService(ISomeType someType)
    {
        if (someType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("someType");
        this.someType = someType;
    }
}
```

The recommended way is to allow the DI container to do this implicitly when your entire object graph is composed (in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)), but it is possible also to do it explicitly (and it makes a better example):

```
ISomeService = container.GetInstance<ISomeService>();
```

Assuming that the container was configured to map ISomeService to SomeService (like I showed before with ISomeType), this one line of code will create an instance of SomeService and automatically inject an instance of SomeType into its constructor.

It is difficult to see the point in a simple example, though. Dependency Injection is meant for complex applications with many types. It simplifies things when the application is complex, but when the application is simple it has a tendency to make things more complex.